# What are the basics to program a minimal git-like code to use it to commit/push changes in your HD to an external driver (Linux)?

Tags: python, linux, algorithm, file, backup

Ok, this is a long shot question. I'm interested in coding an application (probably in Python, but it can be C to an extent) to run in Linux that searches for modification in files on my HD and update to an **external driver** those to modifications to copies of those same files (or new ones) existing in my HD. Something like git can do easily by commit/push actions to a git tree (i.e. in a server).

I'm looking for tips of which features I don't want to forget and also some algorithms or strategies to try to make this the fastest possible after the first run (the copy of the entire HD -- actually, the home folder of my user). Indication on applications that do this are also appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to recreate rsync.

Comment: thanks. @btilly. I would accept this as the answer, if you bother to create it.